# jQuery multiple selectors syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

Guys is this syntax correct? I'm trying to make a `dropdown select` and get the value but I'm not sure if this syntax of multiple selectors are correct

```
var countries = [];
var locations = [];
var zips = [];
$.each($(".country option:selected, .location option:selected ,.zip option:selected"), function(){            
  countries.push($(this).val());
  locations.push($(this).val());
  zips.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: can you explain it clearly? you want to save the value in the array if any of the 3 dropdowns is change..Is that correct? or if any of the three is change you want to get all the 3 values?

Comment: This syntax and approach is correct to get all three values together.......

Comment: I want to save the value in the array if any of the 3 dropdowns is change

Comment: Please take a look at my revised code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing can be correct. You are using the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback) method. If you are targeting `jQuery` objects, I'd go with the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) method. I've written a 3rd method to properly place the values into the correct array. When in doubt, please reference the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/). It's packed full of information and useful examples.

```js
/* Method 1 - jQuery.each( object, callback ) */
var countries = [];
var locations = [];
var zips      = [];
$.each($('.country option:selected, .location option:selected, .zip option:selected'), function(index, value) {
    countries.push($(this).val());
    locations.push($(this).val());
    zips.push($(this).val());
});
console.log('Method 1 - countries', countries);
console.log('Method 1 - locations', locations);
console.log('Method 1 - zips', zips);

/* Method 2 - .each( function ) */
var countries = [];
var locations = [];
var zips      = [];
$('.country option:selected, .location option:selected, .zip option:selected').each(function() {
    countries.push($(this).val());
    locations.push($(this).val());
    zips.push($(this).val());
});
console.log('Method 2 - countries', countries);
console.log('Method 2 - locations', locations);
console.log('Method 2 - zips', zips);

/* Suggested Method */
var countries = [];
var locations = [];
var zips      = [];
$('.country option:selected, .location option:selected, .zip option:selected').each(function() {
    if($(this).parents('.country').length) countries.push($(this).val());
    if($(this).parents('.location').length) locations.push($(this).val());
    if($(this).parents('.zip').length) zips.push($(this).val());
});
console.log('Suggested Method - countries', countries);
console.log('Suggested Method - locations', locations);
console.log('Suggested Method - zips', zips);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="country">
    <option>USA</option>
</select>
<select class="location">
    <option>Florida</option>
</select>
<select class="zip">
    <option>32935</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The methods are useful too

Comment: The `jQuery` selector builds an object for you. Feel free to view it in your console to see what is the best way to manipulate it. (i.e. `console.log($('.selector'));`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiselector like following syntax.

```js
$('#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3').css('border','1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <label id="lbl1">Label 1 </label> <br/>
 <label id="lbl2">Label 2 </label> <br/>
 <label id="lbl3">Label 3 </label>
 
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: The answer is useful but I want to know if $('#example option:selected, #examples option:selected') is valid

Answer (score 0):

This will print the output in console.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  console.log('hi');
  //console.log($('.country option:selected, .location option:selected').val());
  
  $('.country option:selected, .location option:selected').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="country">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
   <option>D</option>
  </select>
  
   <select class="location">
   <option>loc1</option>
   <option>loc2</option>
   <option>loc3</option>
   <option>loc4</option>
  </select>
  
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="get"/>
```